# How to launch Android-sdk emulator?

Tags: android, emulators

I recently installed android-sdk (`apt install android-sdk android-sdk-platform-23 git libgradle-android-plugin-java`). But do not manage to launch the emulator.

I expected to run an `./android` script in `/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools`   or in any other related directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android Developer's website](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html):

```
$ emulator -avd avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]
```

Or,

```
$ emulator @avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]
```

Where `emulator` is found at `/Android/sdk/tools/emulator/`. To find AVD devices available for emulation, you can list AVD device names in your `Android` folder (or `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable, if overridden) using `$ emulator -list-avds`.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the AVD Manager from within the Android Studio GUI.  It is the button just above where the mouse is in this screenshot (just made using AS 2.3, 3.0 is similar location and look)

[image]